# Mysql: DELETE with IN subquery

Tags: mysql

```
DELETE FROM images WHERE image_id IN(
    (SELECT i.image_id FROM images i
    LEFT JOIN ads a ON i.ad_id=a.id
        WHERE ISNULL(a.id))
)
```

I need to accomplish this query. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks ;)

Comment: How is `a.id` in the join, but also null? I would think your SELECT wouldn't work.

Comment: @John Giotta: It's a LEFT join, so OP is looking for rows in `images` where the `images.ad_id` column does not have a corresponding entry in the `ads` table, hence `a.id` would be NULL in those cases.

Comment: @Joe Stefanelli - You're absolutely right. I didn't factor that in correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DELETE i
    FROM images i
        LEFT JOIN ads a ON i.ad_id=a.id
    WHERE ISNULL(a.id)
```